# drools - arraylist access wth multiple condition

Tags: java, drools

I have an object A which has list of Object B.

```
Class A{
    List<B> bList;
}

Class B{
    String code;//Values QT1,QT2.....QT5
    Boolean answer;
}
```

B is like a questionnaire object. A hold all questionares, there will be always 5 questions (may get added in future) QT1 to QT5 with answer in true, false or null.
I need to fire a logic when for any QTx answer is null or QT1, QT2 is true. I have implemented as below but its not working. What is wrong with this?

```
rule "validateQuestions"
ruleflow-group "validate"
dialect "mvel"
when
    $a : A(bList.empty == false)
    B(code == "QT1",answer == true) from $a.bList
    B(code == "QT2",answer == true) from $a.bList
    B(code == "QT3",answer == null) from $a.bList
    B(code == "QT4",answer == null) from $a.bList
    B(code == "QT5",answer == null) from $a.bList
then
    //("Logic Here")
```

There will always be 5 QTx and this can be any combination of answers with true false or null.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `answer != null`?  Or just, `B(code == "QT3", answer)`?

Comment: When answer is null then it need to go to then section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rule "validateQuestions"
when
    $a: A()
    B( code in ("QT1", "QT2") && answer == true ||
       code in ("QT3", "QT4", "QT5") && answer == null ) from $a.bList
then
```

You don't need to test List.empty.

Make sure to read the documentation about the semantics of a "pattern" in the when part of a rule - I'm not going to repeat it all (binding to facts, implied conjunction,...) here. Also, check the documentation about constraint operators (&&, ||, in, not in,...).

Comment: Thanks. But if answer is null the rule wont be fired right? I want it to be fired. Also I think the rule will always get fired as code is always Qt1 .to Qt5

Comment: Ah, yes, overlooked that.  - I'm not sure whether you need to have all five QTx present in the list *or* want to fire for any QT/answer combination as specified. Please modify your question to be more outspoken.

Comment: Modified question, I need to fire the rule when for any QTx answer is null or QT1's answer is true or QT2's answer is true.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure whether I understand when the rule should fire, but you should have enough material to complete your task. - If all five B facts must be present (in a certain form) then the rule should be similar to the one in your question.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have enough material to complete. Did a read @  http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter